# CRAN Package check page shows error for previously submitted package

Tags: r, cran

I was about to send updated package to CRAN. Then I am asked to agree that I fixed following issues found in previous package (which was added to CRAN anyway).

But how to fix this? How to make package installable on `r-oldrel-osx-x86_64`

Google doesn't give any hints :-(

[image]

Comment: Can you click on the error to see what the error message actually is? There's no much to go on here. Usually you can see the results of the test.

Comment: @MrFlick Ah, an 10d10T moment ...... When I click through it says `requires R >=  3.5.0`, which is something I have always been coding on. Oh well, will send package in this case .....